# iOS: Autolayout stretching height of UIView too much (Xcode 8, Swift 3)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, autolayout, constraints

At the bottom of the screen I have a view with a button to change color as shown here: [image: iPhone 7 image]

However, after resetting all constraints to suggested constraints, everything in the view is fine except the UIView on the bottom, when run on iPhone 7 Plus: [image: iPhone 7 Plus image]

I'm not exactly sure what constraints to add in order to make the image the normal height. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can u show us what are the constraints added to the bottom view?

Comment: @Badhan Ganesh http://imgur.com/a/4KIqY   - there is an imageview hidden underneath the bottom view that appears when that button with the color picker image is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The superview **(Bottom view)** should have these constraints:

1. **Bottom space** to container (outer view)
2. **Leading space** to container (outer view)
3. **Trailing space** to container (outer view)

And the **button containing image** should have the following constraints:

1. **aspect ratio**
2. **Center Horizontally** to container (bottom view)
3. **Bottom space** to container (bottom view)
4. **Top space** to container (bottom view)

Setting the **aspect ratio** of the button will not make the button look ugly (distorted aspect ratio) on iPhone 7 Plus.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Kindly upvote and accept the answer. Happy to help :)